# Hibernate LocalDate conversion

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, timezone

Both my application and the database are on *America/Sao_Paulo* timezone.

The database is Oracle 19c and the application is using:

- Spring 2.7.8
- Hibernate 5.6.15.Final
- Java 11

My problem is saving LocalDate or LocalDateTime to Oracle using JPA entities.

The table columns are all using the *DATE* type and the problem happens if I map them to *LocalDate* or *LocalDateTime* properties. The problem only happens on days where Daylight Time Savings starts.

Let's say I have 2 properties:

```
@Column(name = "holiday1")
private LocalDate holiday1;

@Column(name = "holiday2")
private LocalDateTime holiday2;
...
entity.setHoliday1(LocalDate.of(2004, 11, 2));
entity.setHoliday2(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0));
```

In this example, 2004-11-02 was the start of DTS in Brazil, on this day there was no midnight, so Hibernate is changing the 00:00 time part to 01:00 whenever it does the INSERT command and I end up with 2004-11-02 01:00:00 on the database.

I tried adding the property *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC* and it made no difference.

If I change the properties' type to *OffsetDateTime* and do:

```
entity.setHoliday1(LocalDateTime.of(2004, 11, 2, 0, 0, 0).atOffset(ZoneOffset.UTC));
```

I end up with 2004-11-02 21:00:00 on the database. However if use both *spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC* and *OffsetDateTime* Hibernate finally inserts 2004-11-02 00:00 on the database.

Is there a way to make Hibernate ignore the local timezone settings and treat LocalDate correctly? I can't globally set the application timezone to UTC or change a huge amount of legacy code to *OffsetDateTime*.

Comment: Can Oracle store a time that didn't exist in your time zone? Just asking to be sure.

Comment: Yes, if I do an INSERT using SQL Developer it ignores the daylight savings time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though JPA 2.2 doesn't support *ZonedDateTime*, Hibernate does. I ended changing the properties to ZonedDateTime and added `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.jdbc.time_zone=UTC`.

This was the only way I found to force Hibernate to behave in the way I expected.

Internally, Hibernate uses TimeStamp to handle OffsetDateTime and Date to handle LocalDate. No matter what I tried, it always uses the default timezone to make the conversion before sending the data to the database.

I also tried setting `spring.datasource.hikari.data-source-properties.oracle.jdbc.timezoneAsRegion` but it made no difference.

Working with Hibernate is quite frustrating, this is not the first time I have to handle some buggy behavior because they re-implemented poorly something already offered by the JDBC driver.

I didn't had the chance to try Hibernate 6, maybe I'll update this answer in the future.

### Update for Hibernate 6.2

Well, it got even worse: LocalDate is still converted using the default timezone, no matter what I tried.

In addition to the previous property, now I also had to add `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.timezone.default_storage=NORMALIZE`.

Despite what the documentation says, after I tried to use `NORMALIZE_UTC`, Oracle started throwing `ORA-01878` errors.

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate usually converts the `LocalDate`, `LocalDateTime` etc. types to `java.sql.Date`, `java.sql.Timestamp` etc. when binding to JDBC. The reason for that is, that not all JDBC drivers support the java.time types.

I don't think that Hibernate does any time zone translation for `LocalDate`, so if the `java.sql.Date` object that is passed to the JDBC driver ends up with a timezone shift in your database, this means that the JDBC driver is doing some conversion. Consult the Oracle documentation about this.